# Spring basic functions

Tags: spring

I'm trying to write a simple app in Spring, and it looks ok, but Swagger doesn't work properly.
Here is my code:

Controler:

```
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rent")
public class RentalControler {
    private RentalService rentalService;

    public RentalControler(RentalService rentalService) {
        this.rentalService = rentalService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/addclient")
    public ResponseEntity<Client> saveClient(@RequestBody Client client) {
        try {
            rentalService.addNewClient(client);
        }
        catch (ValidationException validationException) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(client);
    }

    @PostMapping("/addcar")
    public ResponseEntity<Car> saveCar(@RequestBody Car car) {
        try {
            rentalService.addNewCar(car);
        }
        catch (ValidationException validationException) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(car);
    }

    @PostMapping("/reserve")
    public ResponseEntity createNewReservation(@RequestBody Reservation reservation) {
        try {
            rentalService.rentCar(reservation);
        }
        catch (ValidationException validationException) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(reservation);
    }

    @GetMapping("getreservations")
    public ResponseEntity<List<RentDetails>> getAllReservations() {
        List<RentDetails> allReservations = rentalService.findAllReservations();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(allReservations);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getall")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Car>> getAllCars(@RequestParam(required=false, name="isRented") Boolean isRented) {
        List<Car> allCars = rentalService.findAllCars(isRented);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(allCars);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Car {
    private final int id;
    private final String make;
    private final String model;
    private final String vin;
    private final CarClass carClass;
    private boolean isRented;
    private final int dailyRate;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public class CarRepository {
    private List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addCar(Car car) throws Exception {
        if (carList.contains(car)) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        carList.add(car);
    }

    public Optional<Car> findCarById(int id) {
        return carList.stream().filter(it -> it.getId() == id).findFirst();
    }

    public void removeAll() {
        carList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Car> findAll() {
        return carList;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class RentalService {
    private final CarRepository carRepository;
    private final ClientRepository clientRepository;
    private final RentRepository rentRepository;

    public RentalService(CarRepository carRepository, ClientRepository clientRepository, RentRepository rentRepository) {
        this.carRepository = carRepository;
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
        this.rentRepository = rentRepository;
    }

    public void rentCar(Reservation reservation) {
        Optional<Client> client = clientRepository.findClientById(reservation.getClientId());
        Optional<Car> car = carRepository.findCarById(reservation.getCarId());

        if(car.isPresent()) {
            Client existingClient = client.get();
            Car existingCar = car.get();
            if(existingCar.isRented()) {
                throw new RentException("Car is currently rented. Please look for another one.");
            }
            else if(existingClient.getRentedCar() != null) {
                throw new RentException("Maximum 1 car per client.");
            }
            else {
                long totalPrice = existingCar.getDailyRate() * DAYS.between(reservation.getEndDate(), reservation.getStartDate());

                RentDetails rentDetails = new RentDetails(
                        UUID.randomUUID(),
                        existingCar,
                        existingClient,
                        totalPrice,
                        reservation.getStartDate(),
                        reservation.getEndDate()
                );
                existingCar.setRented(true);
                existingClient.setRentedCar(existingCar);
                rentRepository.save(rentDetails);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new ValidationException("Car doesn't exist!");
        }
    }

    public void addNewClient(Client client) {
        if (isValid(client.getName())) {
            throw new ValidationException("Name is required!");
        }
        if (isValid(client.getSurname())) {
            throw new ValidationException("Surname is required!");
        }
        if (isValid(client.getCity())) {
            throw new ValidationException("City is required!");
        }

        try {
            clientRepository.addClient(client);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DatabaseException("Database error: ", e);
        }
    }

    public void addNewCar(Car car) {
        if (isValid(car.getVin())) {
            throw new ValidationException("VIN is required!");
        }
        if (isValid(car.getMake())) {
            throw new ValidationException("Make is required!");
        }

        try {
            carRepository.addCar(car);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DatabaseException("Database error: ", e);
        }
    }

    public Optional<Car> findCarById(int id) {
        return carRepository.findCarById(id);
    }

    private static boolean isValid(String attribute) {
        return attribute == null || attribute.isBlank();
    }

    public List<Car> findAllCars(Boolean isRented) {
        List<Car> carList = carRepository.findAll();

        if(isRented != null) {
            return carList.stream().filter(it -> isRented.equals(it.isRented())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        else {
            return carList;
        }
    }

    public List<RentDetails> findAllReservations() {
        List<RentDetails> reservationList = rentRepository.findAll();

        return reservationList;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class RentException extends RuntimeException {
        private final String messsage;
}
```

I'm expecting that someone can look into it and tell my why isn't it working. I tried different versions of Swagger, looked for it online, but none of the previous answers helped me at all. If you need I can paste some more in the comments, since its only a fragment of code, but I believe it should be enough to see into the problem.